# How to make my text print at top / begining of an excell sheet cell

Tags: excel

I want to write the text starting from the beginning of Excel cell. In one cell i wrote multiple lines by using Alt+Enter.  For all other cells, when i started typing, it is staring from the last row. It should start from the top, i.e, at the beginning of the cell. Please look into the image.

I am trying to do this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/puX8w.jpg

Now my question is : 
How do i start from the top of the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the format of the cell as vertically align "top". I can just see in your image that the vertical align "bottom" mini-icon on the ribbon is highlighted. These are the mini-icons just above the horizontal alignment icons and to the right of font settings.